# Database transaction issue with foreign key constraints

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys

I have a question according to SQL-databases in general:

Let's say, I have the entity types `A(a_id: PK; ...)`, `B(b_id: PK; ...)` and `AB(A_id: PK, FK; B_id: PK, FK; ...)`. As you can see, the last one is a join table with foreign key constraints.

Since I have a abstraction layer, which treats every entity and every relation as "object" (a RESTful graph database), the following statements (SQL-pseudocode) shall be treated equally:

1.)

```
BEGIN;
    INSERT A;
    INSERT B;
    INSERT AB;
COMMIT;
```

2.)

```
BEGIN;
    INSERT A;
    INSERT AB;
    INSERT B;
COMMIT;
```

3.)

```
BEGIN;
    INSERT AB;
    INSERT A;
    INSERT B;
COMMIT;
```

Of course option 1 shall work in every SQL DBMS. But what's with option 2 and 3. Do this statements work (transaction context) or do they break the foreign key constraints?

In the second case (broken foreign key constraints), is there a general way to insert data (as mentioned in the examples) in the correct order? Does some kind of reflection or something similar exist?

Cheers.

Comment: Depends on the implementation, plus: `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`

Comment: Tank you. Works for me.